# How to use .replace to replace the string in a array

Tags: javascript, jquery

need to replace GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) to IST
dynamically for multiple array list

for now my array list has 6 entries. need to replace for all the array list .

```
function getTimeAccordingtoTimeZone(utc){
    utc  = new Date(Date.parse(utc));
    var dateUTC = utc ;
    var dateIST = new Date(dateUTC);
    //date shifting for IST timezone (+5 hours and 30 minutes)
    var current_time_zone = getCurrentTimeZone();
    var hour_diff = parseInt(current_time_zone);
    var minute_diff = current_time_zone - hour_diff;
    minute_diff = minute_diff*60;
    dateIST.setHours(dateIST.getHours() + hour_diff);
    dateIST.setMinutes(dateIST.getMinutes() + minute_diff);
    var new_date = dateIST;
    return new_date;
}
```

```
new_date returns
Tue Jan 15 2019 22:49:04 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Tue Jan 15 2019 22:49:04 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Tue Jan 15 2019 22:49:04 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Tue Jan 15 2019 22:49:04 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Tue Jan 15 2019 22:49:04 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Tue Jan 15 2019 22:49:04 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Comment: You want to convert IST to UTC?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert date to another timezone in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript)

Comment: Use a loop to iterate over your array and call the conversion function for each value, what exactly is your problem here?

Comment: @StefanHariton it is already converted to IST. just need to replace the words to IST because the word India standard time is too long

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose you use moment JS to format the string.

In your case, the following code will help you:

```
const moment = require('moment');
date = moment();
const dateString = `${date.format('ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss')} IST`
console.log(dateString);
```

[MomentJs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) Documentation